# How to solve RequestTooBigException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760 in Wildfly?

Tags: java, wildfly

I have a web application in **Wildfly** and when I'm trying to upload a file bigger than 10MB, I'm getting the following error:

```
io.undertow.server.RequestTooBigException: UT000020: Connection terminated as request was larger than 10485760
```

Please, how can I solve this error?

Comment: http://www.mastertheboss.com/web/jboss-web-server/configuring-wildfly-upload-file-size/

Comment: Thank you @DawoodibnKareem. With your link and this one (https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3084671) I solved my problem. Would you like to put the answer or I put it?

Comment: Do whatever you like.  I don't intend to revisit this question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I solved my problem by putting the **max-post-size** in the standalone.xml, as the example below:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:3.1">
<buffer-cache name="default"/>
<server name="default-server">
    <ajp-listener name="ajp" max-post-size="1073741824" socket-binding="ajp"/>
    <http-listener name="default" max-post-size="1073741824" socket-binding="http" redirect-socket="https"/>
    <https-listener name="https" max-post-size="1073741824" socket-binding="https" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
    ...
</server>
...
```

In this example, the value is configurated to 1GB, but you can configure the value you want.

If you use Nginx, don't forget to configure the **client_max_body_size**.

**Helpful links:**

https://access.redhat.com/solutions/3084671

http://www.mastertheboss.com/web/jboss-web-server/configuring-wildfly-upload-file-size/

Answer (score 4):

I just add one more answer if someone found this question by googling this problem but for server UNDERTOWN with spring-boot implementation (it was my case).

Just add this to your yml files:

```
spring:
  servlet:
    multipart:
      max-file-size: 100MB
      max-request-size: 100MB
```